# Fourier transform of a continuous,compactly supported function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider a function $f$ which is continuous on $\mathbb{R^n}$ with compact support.
Does its Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(x)e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot \xi} \,dx$ always lie in $\mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R^n})$ ?

I would say yes if  f is  $k^{th}$ differentiable for sufficiently large k. But what if f is merely contiuous? I think in this case its Fourier transform can decay slowly, but I fail to find a counterexample.

Any hint is highly aprreciated!!!

Comment: I'm no expert but since the Fourier transform of the indicator function is not in L1 my first guess would be to take the indicator function and make it continuous but with really high slopes at the edge, and keep it non-differentiable. Just my first idea but maybe you really do need the discontinuity with that to take it out of L1

Comment: Indeed, the counterexample space is quite bad since every function in $H^{n/2+\epsilon}$ has integrable Fourier transform (and even more precisely $B^{n/2}_{2,1}$). So in dimension $1$ you are looking for continuous functions that have not more than $1/2$ derivative in $L^2$. These are usually built by summing little blocks with the good scaling.

Comment: @Aphyd a way to achieve your idea would be to take a function such as $(1 - |x|^p)^{1/p}$ in $[-1, 1]$. However, my intuition is that instead of the $1/\xi$ of the indicator function, it will lead to $1/\xi^{1 + \epsilon}$ which is $L^1$. Perhaps a sharper function could lead to $1/{\xi \log|\xi|}$ at infinity, which is not $L^1$.